# How to make 1 side of div curve in css

Tags: html, css

I want to create two divs in row then do their left and right side  curve then place image inside them, how I can achieve following image ?

[image]

I tried this but it not showing my desired output.

```css
#box{ Display:flex; }
#left{ height: 300px; width: 40%}
#Right{height: 300px; width: 40%; border-radius:30%}
```

```html
<div id="box"> 
  <div id="left"> 
  </div>
  <div id="right"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question could use some clarity regarding the "curve" comment vs just the diagonal in the image presented

Answer (score 0):

`display` instead of `Display` and ID names must be exact so `#right` instead of `#Right`.

You also forgot to add `;` after `width` and `border-radius`.

Comment: `#right`, instead of `#Right` is correct. The rest of what you say are just warnings, but no errors.

Comment: Doesn't matter if they're "just warnings" or not; not adding `;` breaks your code.

Comment: No, the last semicolon will not break your code. It is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You need do this:

**Create a structure in the parent tag**

After you need centralize the elements, apply the css code for generate a polygon.

```
<style>

#box{ display:flex;width:100vw;height:100vh;flex-direction:row;align-items:center;justify-content:center;background:#ddd;}
#left{ height: 300px; width: 40%; background:#333;display:flex;position:absolute;left:0;clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 85% 55%, 74% 100%, 0% 100%);}
#right{height: 300px; width: 40%; background:#666;display:flex;position:absolute;right:0;clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 13% 48%);}

</style>

    <div id="box"> 
        <div id="left"> 
        </div>
        <div id="right"> 
        </div>
    </div>
```